# Static field initialization order

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Is there any trap in static constant field initialization order?

```
template <typename T>
struct constant_test {

    static const T PI;
    static const T FULL_CIRCLE;
    static const T HALF_CIRCLE;
    static const T DEG_TO_RAD;

};

template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::PI = 3.141592653589f;
template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::FULL_CIRCLE = 360.0f;
template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::HALF_CIRCLE = constant_test<T>::FULL_CIRCLE / 2;
template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::DEG_TO_RAD = constant_test<T>::PI / constant_test<T>::HALF_CIRCLE;

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    // uncomment to make it work
    // float test_ref = constant_test<float>::HALF_CIRCLE;
    char buf[128];
    sprintf_s(buf, 128, "Value: %f", constant_test<float>::DEG_TO_RAD);
    OutputDebugStringA(buf); // prints "Value: 1.#INF00"
    return 0;
}
```

An expression `constant_test<float>::DEG_TO_RAD` magically returns `-Infinity`

If i remove template parameter and make them only float then constant is evaluated correctly (0.017453)

If i add reference to HALF_CIRCLE constant then it's also evaluated correctly

I'm using MSVC 2013 SP 1.

Why?
What i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code is converted to a console application and use g++, it prints out the correct value (g++4.8.2, OS X):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct constant_test {

    static const T PI;
    static const T FULL_CIRCLE;
    static const T HALF_CIRCLE;
    static const T DEG_TO_RAD;

};

template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::PI = 3.141592653589f;
template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::FULL_CIRCLE = 360.0f;
template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::HALF_CIRCLE = constant_test<T>::FULL_CIRCLE / 2;
template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::DEG_TO_RAD = constant_test<T>::PI / constant_test<T>::HALF_CIRCLE;

int main()
{
    // uncomment to make it work
    //float test_ref = constant_test<float>::HALF_CIRCLE;
    cout << "Value: " << constant_test<float>::DEG_TO_RAD << endl; // correct result

    char buf[128];
    sprintf(buf, "Value: %f", constant_test<float>::DEG_TO_RAD );
    cout << buf << endl; // again correct
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Value: 0.0174533
Value: 0.017453
```

The static constants are initialized in order, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011133/3093378, so you should have `constant_test<T>::DEG_TO_RAD` initialized when you display it (and it looks it is, from the code above).

Comment: Do u think ..Microsoft?

Comment: Did you try to run the above code in a console-like application?

Comment: I still get the same correct result if I use the typical `sprintf` as  `sprintf(buf, "Value: %f", constant_test<float>::DEG_TO_RAD );`, then `cout << buf << endl;`

Comment: direct copy-paste of your version. cmd.exe: `constant_test\Debug>constant_test.exe`
`Value: 1.#INF`... =) I don't sure is it allowed to reference static field from another static field in the same compilation unit. But why not.. looks like a bug

Comment: I am not sure, I don't have Windows so I cannot reproduce your problem, but on my system it runs fine with both `g++` and `clang++`

Comment: I guess that the order is sequential only for explicitly specialized templated members (C++ standard, 3.6.2). See also the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819131/c-static-member-initalization-template-fun-inside Just make them const and initialize them in a constructor.

Comment: And I also realized that in `g++`, I can change the order the declarations and still the compiler arrange them in the "proper" order, i.e. define the non-dependent types first.

Comment: If replace `DEG_TO_RAD = constant_test<T>::PI / static_cast<T>(180.0);` then it works. Looks like MSVC bug.

Comment: Now I am not even sure how valid such an initialization is: `template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::PI = 3.141592653589f;` The type `T` is not known at this point, so don't really understand how this works.

Comment: Template code is compiled only on template instantiation. At this point type is known.

Comment: I know, but in your code it looks like the static variables should come into existence before `main()` (where you first instantiate the template), however at the point where you declare the static ones the type is not known. I am a bit confused by this.

Comment: I guess that only when you instantiate the template for a given type, all of the static variables are initialized (for that given type).

Comment: Yep. But... MSVC initializes them very strange. If there is no direct reference in code to some constant then it thinks that this constant is zero. Thats why i get `infinity`--

Comment: Btw, I posted a question similar to yours, hope we can get some answers :) And indeed, according to the standard, a static variable is implicitly zero if you do not initialize it (i.e. if define it outside the class as `static int Foo::i;`, then `A::i` is 0 implicitly), but otherwise should have the value given by the initialization.

Comment: Correct initialization order is not guaranteed for the relevant members. See the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to

- [c++ - Initialization order of static data inside class template - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011133/5267751)
- [c++ - Template static members initialization order - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23841234/5267751)

there are the following types of initialization:

- **static initialization**

  - **zero initialization**: for example `int x;` in global scope
  - **constant initialization**: for example `int x=1+2;` where `1+2` is a constant expression
- **dynamic initialization**

  - **ordered initialization**: for example

    - `std::vector<int> x{1, 2, 3};` in global scope, or
    - `template<> std::vector<int> A<int>::x{1, 2, 3};` (explicit specialization)
  - **unordered initialization**: for example `template<class T> std::vector<T> A<T>::x;`

See [What is Unordered dynamic initialization, Partially-ordered dynamic initialization and Ordered dynamic initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951527/what-is-unordered-dynamic-initialization-partially-ordered-dynamic-initializati) for what the terms mean.

In this case

```
template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::PI = 3.141592653589f;
template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::FULL_CIRCLE = 360.0f;
```

are constant initialization(s), and because they're floating-point type in this case they're not constexpr, according to [c++ - Initializing constexpr with const: Different treatment for int and double - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41141734/5267751).

```
template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::HALF_CIRCLE = constant_test<T>::FULL_CIRCLE / 2;
template <typename T> const T constant_test<T>::DEG_TO_RAD = constant_test<T>::PI / constant_test<T>::HALF_CIRCLE;
```

are dynamic unordered initialization.

As such, the initialization order of the 2 last ones are not guaranteed.

Comment: Potentially relevant: They are only not constant-initialized because `T` is a floating-point type. For an integral type they would be.

Comment: `const` integral type variables initialized by constant expressions behave as if they were `constexpr` when used in expressions. It is a specific exception to the requirement that used variables be `constexpr`.