# Reference to global variable cause SEGV error when I add an empty constructor to the factory class

Tags: c++

I have the following code to provide a factory to create an encoder/decoder for a given data type and encoding scheme (BITPACK, PLAIN, etc), and the code works.

```
class Encoding {
 public:
  virtual std::unique_ptr<Encoder> encoder() = 0;

  virtual std::unique_ptr<Decoder> decoder() = 0;
};

template <class E, class D>
class EncodingTemplate : public Encoding {
 public:
  std::unique_ptr<Encoder> encoder() override {
    return std::unique_ptr<Encoder>(new E());
  }

  std::unique_ptr<Decoder> decoder() override {
    return std::unique_ptr<Decoder>(new D());
  }
};

namespace u32 {

class PlainEncoder {...};
class PlainDecoder {...};
class BitpackEncoder {...};
class BitpackDecoder {...};

EncodingTemplate<PlainEncoder, PlainDecoder> plainEncoding;
EncodingTemplate<BitpackEncoder, BitpackDecoder> bitpackEncoding;

Encoding& EncodingFactory::Get(EncodingType encoding) {
  switch (encoding) {
    case PLAIN:
      return plainEncoding;
    case BITPACK:
      return bitpackEncoding;
    default:
      return plainEncoding;
  }
}
}  // namespace u32

// This is where we invoke the encoder
class BlockBuilder {

void Build() {
....
std::unique_ptr<Encoder> key_encoder = u32::EncodingFactory::Get(BITPACK).encoder();
};
```

Now I want to modify the factory to create a shared encoder/decoder and reuse it. So I add a constructor to `EncodingTemplate` (This is the first step, and it's just an empty constructor.) Then the code stopped working and AddressSanitizer complains about seg fault.

```
SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x55ca3c817eec bp 0x7fffe7bdd190 sp 0x7fffe7bdd090 T0)
    BlockBuilder::Build(): block_builder.cc:16
    BlockBuilder::Add(leveldb::Slice const&, leveldb::Slice const&)
    BlockReadBenchmark::BlockReadBenchmark()
BlockReadBenchmark_Normal_Benchmark::BlockReadBenchmark_Normal_Benchmark()
    __static_initialization_and_destruction_0
    _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z13binary_sorterii
    __libc_csu_init
    __libc_start_main
    _start
```

Here's my new `EncodingTemplate`, it only adds an empty constructor.

```
class EncodingTemplate : public Encoding {
 public:
    EncodingTemplate() {} // Only add an empty constructor here

  std::unique_ptr<Encoder> encoder() override {
    return std::unique_ptr<Encoder>(new E());
  }

  std::unique_ptr<Decoder> decoder() override {
    return std::unique_ptr<Decoder>(new D());
  }
};
```

A weird thing is, I can reproduce the error in my project. I comment out the constructor and the code works. I uncomment it, and the error comes back. But when I try to create a minimized working example, I failed to reproduce it.

Can anyone help me figure out what is happening? I really have no idea why a reference to a global variable could cause SEG FAULT. And what does a constructor have to do with it.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the rest of the call stack look like? I'm guessing that `BlockBuilder::Build` is called as part of a static initialization but the `bitpackEncoding` variable has not been initialized yet..

Comment: What does the base `Encoding` class look like? What is/are its constructor(s)?

Comment: @Botje @adrian-mole Thanks for the hint. I have added the remaining call stacks to the question. The error happens in my benchmark code with Google Benchmark. I have also added the code of `Encoding`, which is an interface with two pure virtual methods.

Comment: @Botje Thanks for your insightful hint! I think you are right. So the cause is the random initialization sequence of global variables and static function calls. When I add a constructor, gcc change the init sequence for some reason and my factory is inited after it was called, which cause the problem. Is that correct?

Comment: And it would be very appreciated if you can give me some suggestions on a better way to implement such factory.

Comment: Correct. Adding a constructor turns your object from plain old data (which simply maps to a zero-initialized chunk of memory at startup)  into something that needs to be explicitly initialized before the program startup. The technical term is "C++ static order initialization fiasco", which has [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822181/prevent-static-initialization-order-fiasco-c) [popular questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913670/the-classical-c-static-initialization-order-fiasco-revisited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical solution to this is the Singleton pattern, since that defers initialization to the first time the object is needed. Since you have a factory already, you can use a function-local `static` variable:

```
Encoding& EncodingFactory::Get(EncodingType encoding) {
  static EncodingTemplate<PlainEncoder, PlainDecoder> plainEncoding;
  static EncodingTemplate<BitpackEncoder, BitpackDecoder> bitpackEncoding;

  switch (encoding) {
    case PLAIN:
      return plainEncoding;
    case BITPACK:
      return bitpackEncoding;
    default:
      return plainEncoding;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tactical note: you still won't have much control over when the object is destroyed, other than after `main` exits, so be careful about using it in the destructors of other objects with static storage duration.